# ANDROID - Google Maps - Cannot "Return Location;" after If Statment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-gps

when my location is null my application force closes. I'm certain it's because the location returns null. I tried using the code with Mock GPS and the code works when it passes through the "if (myLocation != null)". I just can't "return myLocation;" after the "if (myLocation == null)"

Please help. Thank you.

```
    @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,

            }, 10);
        }
        return;
    }

    gMap = googleMap;

        if(!gMap.isMyLocationEnabled())
            gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


    if (myLocation == null) {
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
        String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    }
```

if I add "return myLocation;" after the "if( myLocation == null )"

[image: LIKE THIS]

It returns an error.
[image: IMAGE OF THE ERROR]
[image: IMAGE OF THE ERROR 2]

Comment: Your method is void, which means it doesn't return a value back. You have it set up to call this method and pass something to it, but it does not return something back.

Comment: simply create a function and use `myLocation` to do whatever you want to do in that function

Comment: @PavneetSingh - function outside the onMapReady?

Comment: you can create a function , move your logic that required the use of  `myLocation` and call that function after this line `myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);`

Answer (score 1):

its because you are using void type return

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
```

use Location type.

```
public Location onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
```

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) is a abstract "call back" usage method, but i can see that you want to have a method to return a Location obj to use. There is several way to do. 
One is use a global object to store the returned result like:

```
private Location location = null;
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){
......
this.location =  myLocation;
}
public void someMethodIUseLocation(){
//TO CALL this.location if need to use 
}
```

just depends on how you wanted to call the way to implement is different

Comment: Hello, I tried it and returns this error. Please see the link. https://i.imgur.com/4hguC8r.png @CbL